# Find factors of a number

Tags: performance, beginner, c, factors

I am a beginner in C. I have just written this program to find the factors of a provided number \$n\$ where \$1\leq n \leq 10^9\$. However, when I input large numbers (e.g. the maximum, \$10^9\$), the program takes a long time to finish finding the larger factors. How do I reduce its time taken? Also, are there any possible improvements for this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a,i;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(i=1;i<(a/2+1);i++){
        if(a%i==0){
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can skip "1" since 1, after 2 you can skip all even numbers.

Comment: @pacmaninbw you can only skip all even numbers if you want to find the prime factors. If you actually want all factors, you still need them.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to perform the prime factorization; then all the factors can be constructed by combining those primes.  That's starting to get too large for a comment, though!

Comment: A quick observation that's too small for an answer - please don't get the bad habit of ignoring the return value from `scanf()`!

Comment: What do you mean by the return value? @TobySpeight

Comment: `int items_read = scanf("%d",&a);  if (items_read != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number\n"); return 1; }` - here `items_read` is the return value of `scanf()`.  It indicates how successful the library function was, but in the sample code, the value is just ignored.

Comment: I see. Are there any drawbacks when ignoring the return value? I wasn't reminded of the importance of that when learning C...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should realize that if \$i\$ is a divisor of \$a\$, then so is \$a / i\$. This way you get two divisors per found divisor.

In the same vein, you only need to search up to \$\sqrt{n}\$, because all factors above that have already been found as the second divisor.

So your code would become:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
        int a,i;
        scanf("%d",&a);
        int bound = ceil(sqrt(a));
        for(i=1; i <= bound; i++) {
                if(a%i==0) {
                        printf("%d\n",i);
                        if(a/i != i) printf("%d\n", a/i);
                }
        }
        printf("%d\n",a);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to list the factors in ascending order? This definitely runs much quicker but it isn't listed in order.

Comment: @54D I'm pretty sure it is possible, but I don't know enough C to answer that. You would probably have to add the `a/i` numbers to some kind of buffer which you then work through after the main loop...

Comment: @54D Also, you never said they should be in order in your question :)

Comment: I realized, sorry about that ^^|| I'll mark this as accepted anyway, because it directly answers the question.

Comment: Even without storage, you could still find the factors in order - iterate from 1 to √a, printing `i` at each match, then repeat the loop downwards back to 1, printing `a/i` at each match.  You have still replaced *a* iterations with 2√a iterations, which is a bargain for any a>4.

Comment: @TobySpeight But you need to check all numbers again if they divide `a`...

Comment: @TobySpeight Fixed the bug for square numbers and added a check in that case to only print the divisor once.

Comment: Yes, that's right (and that's the trade-off against storage - I'd use the storage, FWIW).  It's still much fewer tests than the original, because the factors below √a are obviously denser than those above.  For large a, √a is *much* less than a/2.

Comment: You can sort the factors by capturing found `i` values (which are found in incrementing order) in a queue and found `a/i` (which are found in decrementing order) in a stack.  When you want to write out the factors in order, you first output the queue and then output the stack. Note you have an edge condition where `i = a/i` that would need to be accommodated (like don't add to stack in this case).